# Change URL for /cat/

Tags: overrides, url, layered-navigation, url-rewrite, .htaccess

I want to put a Magento Redirect rule to change the URL for filtering products and category.

When I use the filter in a category, the urls are look like this :

**FROM**: http://example.com/redwine

**TO**  : http://example.com/redwine//cat/france

So, basically I want to remove the `//cat`. How can I do this trough either `.htaccess` or a *hack in magento*?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove it entirely because the layered navigation filters need a request variable to determine *what* to filter. But you can change "cat" to something else.

It is defined in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_requestVar = 'cat';
}
```

There is a setter `setRequestVar()` but unfortunately there is no way to call it between the filter being instantiated and being applied, without rewriting either the filter model or the filter block.

I would prefer to rewrite the block because the URL parameter is related to the user interface:

```
class Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Category 
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category
{
    protected function _prepareFilter()
    {
        $this->_filter->setRequestVar('dog');
        return parent::_prepareFilter();
    }
}
```

*Since you are asking for a HACK, you could change one of the classes directly instead, but I won't recommend hacking the core. And no, copying the file to app/code/local is not better.*

Now the URLs are like this: `http://example.com/redwine/dog/france`. That is, the links in the filter navigation ar built this way, you could not accomplish this with `.htaccess` rewrite rules.

Comment: Hi @fschmengler thanks for your input! The reason for me wanting to change the filer, is primarily to navigate directly to the sub-category, for examle if i have a sub-cat in redwine called france, i can input to the url http://example.com/redwine/france and i get to the sub-cat. I am trying to achieve the same with the filter, because then i can output the category description etc. when a user uses filter. How can i achieve this? Because it won't help if I just change the cat to something else.